# How can I mock this file, can't covered setTimeout callback

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, antd

need test below code, how can i mock the setTimeout callback

```
import { message } from 'antd';

const showMessage = ({ type = 'info', text }) => {
  message.destroy();
  setTimeout(() => {
     message[type](text); // this line can't covered
  }, 10);
};
export function error(text) {
  showMessage({ type: 'error', text });
}
export function info(text) {
  showMessage({ type: 'info', text });
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your test?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jest.runAllTimers()](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/timer-mocks.html#run-all-timers) :

```js
jest.mock('antd');
const { message } = require('antd');

const { error } = require('../message');

describe('src/shared/utils/message', () => {
  describe('#error', () => {
    it('should call message.error', () => {
      error('dummy');
      jest.runAllTimers();

      expect(message.error).toBeCalledWith('dummy');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but showMessage is a private fuction, and no callbak param

Comment: You can mock/spy `message`

Comment: @JediYuan I updated my answer with a complete code sample.

Comment: Got an error 

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledWith(expected)

    Expected mock function to have been called with:
      ["dummy"]
    But it was not called.

Comment: You may need `jest.useFakeTimers();` at the top